# How to trigger an action when NSWindowController loses its focus or stops beign first responder

Tags: macos, focus, xcode5, nswindowcontroller

currently developing an app for Mac OSX with Xcode 5.1

I need to trigger an action when a NSWindowController loses its focus like when a user click outside of the window

I was looking for a pre-built method like

```
- (void)windowDidLoad
```

or sort of which triggers when a user touches outside but I can't find anything

any help I'll appreciate